# A graph with minimum degree $k+2$ contains any $(k+3)$-vertex tree as a subgraph?

Tags: graph-theory, trees, graph-isomorphism

Let $k$ be a positive integer and let $T$ be a tree of order $k+3$. If $G$ is a graph with minimum degree at least $k+2$, prove that $G$ contains a subgraph isomorphic to $T$.

Any solutions or hints are greatly appreciated. I'm so lost.

Comment: I just noticed: [Trees that are isomorphic to a subgraph of a graph G.](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/321039/91818), [Prove that T is a subgraph of G](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/441978/91818), [The isomorphic subgraph problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/8500/91818), and [Tree with $k$ edges is a subgraph of any graph with all vertices of degree $\geq k$.](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/866226/91818).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sketch of a proof.  We proceed algorithmically:  we begin with the empty subgraph $S$.

*Initial step*: Pick a vertex $v^{(T)}$ of the tree and match it up with any vertex $v^{(G)}$ in $G$.  Mark $v^{(T)}$ as "used" and add $v^{(G)}$ to the subgraph $S$.

*Recursive step*: If there is any unused vertex $w^{(T)}$ in the tree which neighbors a used vertex $u^{(T)}$, we pair it up with a neighbor $w^{(G)}$ of $u^{(G)}$ in $G$ which is not already pair up.  We add $w^{(G)}$ and the edge $w^{(G)}u^{(G)}$ to the subgraph.  We mark $w^{(T)}$ as "used".

We complete the proof by arguing (a) that either $w^{(T)}$ and $u^{(T)}$ exist, or we are "done" (since trees are connected), (b) that $w^{(G)}$ always exists (due to the degree constraint), and (c) the subgraph $S$ is isomorphic to $T$ via the isomorphism $x^{(T)} \mapsto x^{(G)}$.